# Is there any Implementation done for CancelablePromptString as its done for CancelablePromptChoice

Tags: botframework

In the bot framework I need generic Implementation for canceling the prompt if user enter cancel or abort. I can see similar Implementation done for Prompt.Choice but not for Prompt.String.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs

Anybody has Implemented anything like this to cancel the Prompt.Double or Prompt.String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you provided is to prompt dialog to user to let user choose if he want to cancel, but based on your description, I think that you may want to listen to user's cancel command, then you can try to handle global message for "Cancel" during middle of any conversation.

Please refer to [Implement global message handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers), to register a global handler for "Cancel".

And here is official [Global Message Handlers Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-GlobalMessageHandlers) you may have a look.

Comment: Feng. Thanks for your answer. Global Message Handlers Resolves it. But I have a question here : can we prompt user if they really want to cancel the conversation or not? if they choose to cancel then i need to cancel it or need to continue where they left it off.

Comment: @Sandip, you can try to send a confirm message in `PrepareAsync` when get `cancel` command, and based on user's selection to `return message.Text;` to confirm cancel task or not.

Comment: awesome. Than you so much !!